# How to create a code-only webview with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use a library that doesn't has a .Net SDK, but as I want to use it only to return a string, I thought I could use it's JS SDK by creating a custom WebView that returns strings (https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-webview-executing-javascript/).

The first problem that I faced was that a CustomRenderer is not called in Xamarin.Forms until the View is added to a Page (or at least I couldn't make it be called). To fix this I added a call to Platform.CreateRenderer in each platform.

It did the trick and the CustomRenderer executed. But when I tried to call a JS function to retrieve a string, the app just hung and stayed that way.

I didn't try to insert the WebView in a Page because I want it to be independent of the page that the app is current on, and as I want a "code-only" html, I don't see the point of adding it somewhere.

### My classes:

JSEvaluator

```
namespace MyNamespace.Views
{
    public class JSEvaluator : WebView
    {
        public static BindableProperty EvaluateJavascriptProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EvaluateJavascript), typeof(Func<string, Task<string>>), typeof(JSEvaluator), null, BindingMode.OneWayToSource);

        public Func<string, Task<string>> EvaluateJavascript
        {
            get { return (Func<string, Task<string>>)GetValue(EvaluateJavascriptProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EvaluateJavascriptProperty, value); }
        }

        public JSEvaluator()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

---

UWP Renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(JSEvaluator), typeof(JSEvaluatorRenderer))]
namespace MyNamespace.UWP.Renderers
{
    public class JSEvaluatorRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public JSEvaluatorRenderer() { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var webView = e.NewElement as JSEvaluator;
            if (webView != null)
                webView.EvaluateJavascript = async (js) =>
                {
                    return await Control.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { js });
                };
        }
    }
}
```

---

Creation and use

```
if (jsEvaluator == null)
{
    jsEvaluator = new JSEvaluator { Source = new HtmlWebViewSource { Html = HTML.html } };

#if __ANDROID__
    Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer(jsEvaluator);
#elif __IOS__
    Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.CreateRenderer(jsEvaluator);
#elif WINDOWS_UWP
    Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.CreateRenderer(jsEvaluator);
#endif
}
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: On `iOS` you can use `JavaScriptCore` to execute JavaScript without an visual control. On Android you are going to have to *display* the `WebView` as its internals are not created until it gets a surface assigned (i.e. it has to be visible).

Comment: Thank you for the info! I tried to search if UWP has this feature and I couldn't find out. But as I have to do the same implementation in all platforms, Android is already limiting. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the WebView to a page, as @SushiHangover said in the comment. With this done, it worked as expected.